# Creating links to external sites in drop down menu

Tags: site-url

Our site was created by a developer before my time at the library and I have been asked to add a link in the drop down menu (http://www.falmouthpubliclibrary.org) to an external site. There are links already - for example if you go to the site and look under For Readers/Books In Print - it links to an external web page.

How is that done?  I can't figure out how to make a new link in the drop down menu.  Thanks for any help.

Peter

Comment: Do you have access to the template code?  This could have been done in dozens of different ways..;)

Comment: Yes but I don't much about it.  I am a newbie to EE.

Comment: You may not know much about EE but we know *nothing* at all about how your site is put together. Help us to help you by giving us as much detail as possible. At the very least you need to give us a clue with some template code. It's impossible to give a definitive answer without this.

Comment: Well then I may be stuck.  I have no history from the consultant that did put the site together - that was 6 years ago.  I was not here at the library.  What template code are you looking for?

Comment: Is there a simple way to add the link to the menu?

Comment: Yes, there is. It's probably something that can take just one minute to change. The problem is that we don't know where to change. EECMS is a really flexible system. There's a lot of ways of do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The links could be done in a number of different ways. They could be:

- manually coded into a template or snippet
- generated from entries within a channel
- output by an add-on

The first place to look is within your template code. This will at least give you a clue as to what is controlling those links.

Look in you templates (start with the homepage) and see if you can work out where the links are being generated. They could be in that template or within an embedded template.

If you can't find anything there, look in Design->Templates->Snippets to see if there is anything there

If you can't find anything in Snippets then look in Add-ons->Modules for any of the following, "NavEE", "Taxonomy" or "Structure". Any of these add-ons could be creating navigation links for you. Another clue that these are being used would be a tag in the template code.

All of these add-ons will handle creation of new links in their own way but you should be able to work it out.